# Why, in generics, does T.getClass() return a Class<?> and not a Class<T>?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

This often leaves us having to do 'unchecked' casts back to `Class<T>` when using Guava's TypeToken:

```java
public <T> T doSomething(T dest) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final Class<T> destClass = (Class<T>) dest.getClass();

    final TypeToken<T> destType = TypeToken.of(destClass);

    ...

    return dest;
}
```

Why was this choice made? Is this due to type erasure or something?

Comment: `getClass()` is a method declared in `Object`. If you were defining such a method on some particular type `T`, the return type could be `<? extends T>`, but since it's defined in Object, its declared return type has to be one that will work for all classes.

Comment: @khelwood That's not really true though. `getClass` is subject to a bit of Java magic "The actual result type is Class<? extends |X|> where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called"

Comment: Reason it returns `Class<? extends Object>` is because your `<T>` is not bound to anything, so, strictly speaking, `T` and `? extends Object` are equivalent. If you constrain `T` to be, for example `T extends CharSequence`, then you can write `Class<? extends CharSequence> cls = dest.getClass();`